# Strpos function in php and an array as needle

Tags: php, arrays, strpos

I want to check the mime-type of uploaded file in php and return true if it is allowed.

I have an array of some part of allowed mime-types like this:

```
$allowedMimes = array('images','word','pdf');
```

images is for jpg/png/gif and word is for doc/docx and pdf for pdf.

the mime-type of an uploaded docx file is for example:

```
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
```

now i need to check it in array.i think i should use strpos but i don't know how use it with an array.

would you help me?

Comment: You wouldn't use `strpos`, but preferrably `in_array` after lowercasing the mime type. (More correctly you would also cut out anything after a `;` - but that rarely happens in practice..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach( $allowedMimes as $mime ) {
   if( strpos( 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document' , $mime ) ) {
    return true;
  }
}
```